# How do native methods on Android interact with the power management lifecycle?

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, java-native-interface

Will Android potentially enter deep sleep (CPU sleeping) while a native method is running?

If so,

- can a native method acquire a wake lock using C calls?
- will the phone wake automatically when there is data available for a native method blocking on a socket read?
- will the phone wake automatically when there is data available for a native method blocking on select or epoll?

If Android does not consider sleeping during native method invocation, how can I ensure that the phone can go to sleep until one of the sockets created in the native code has data ready to receive?

Some background:

The Android site's [JNI tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) suggests that "Android does not suspend threads executing native code. If garbage collection is in progress, or the debugger has issued a suspend request, Android will pause the thread the next time it makes a JNI call." - it appears to be a reference to suspension of individual threads rather than putting the phone into suspend/sleep mode.  Other than that, I couldn't find any specific comments about suspend/sleep behavior.

Comment: My suspicion would be that the fact that code is running natively rather than under the dvm has no impact on sleep behavior - anything related to that would be delivered on the UI thread which must be properly handled regardless.  As for waking on receipt of data, that would really depend on how the particular network interface is handled when asleep.  Something fancy like google cloud messaging should result in a wakeup consistent with its API but to expect some random enduring TCP connection suddenly having traffic to wake it up seem more doubtful, though might work in some implementations?

Answer (score 0):

To find more information about the Android PowerManagement Natively you want to look at the source documents

http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/power_management.html

As for using the wakelock from native the documentation warns that you can destabilizer the system doing so.

`User space native libraries (any hardware function in //device/lib/hardware/ meant to serve as supporting libraries for Android runtime) should never call into Android Power Management directly (see the image above). Bypassing the power management policy in the Android runtime will destabilize the system.`